# Symfony form has ManyToOne field but still requires the __tostring() function

Tags: symfony

In a Symfony entity that stores the address information of a client I have made a ManyToOne connection with a entity that contains all countries. So the entity has de following link:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country_code", type="string", length=2)
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_code", referencedColumnName="country_code")
 */
private $countryCode;
```

In the form generated of this entity I have defined it like this:

```
       ->add('countryCode', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyBundle:Country',
            'choice_label' => 'name_en',
            'choice_value' => 'country_code',
            'data' => 'nl',
        ))
```

So it does not store the primary key but the country_code a two letter code like "nl" for the Netherlands.

Then I have to add __tostring() code to make it work, but why is that? I though the __tostring function would not be required anymore as there is already a ManyToOne connection.

```
public function __toString()
{
    return strval($this->countryCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your entity you just have to write this :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PathTo/YourBundle/Entity/Country")
*/
private $country;
```

Then $country will be a reference to a Country Entity (it's ID in the DB),
and will allow you to acces ALL IT'S FIELDS.

After that in your form you should not use

```
->add('country', 'entity', array(....
```

As this syntax is deprecated and use instead :

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType; //don't forget it on top of your form file


->add('country', EntityType::class, array(....
```

As you probably want to order your countries by alphabetical order you will use a query to do so and eventually your code may look like :

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

...

->add('country', EntityType::class, array(
      'class' => 'MyBundle:Country',
      'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->orderBy('c.name_en', 'ASC');
                },
      'choice_label' => 'name_en',
      'data' => 'nl'
      ))
```

you normally don't have to worry about choice_value, which will be the unique ID of the chosen country : when you'll acces your Client Entity, you will do :

```
$client->getCountry()->getCountryCode() ;
```

to get the country code.

Comment: I changed the ManyToOne and removed the __tostring() function and now the Country is linked in the database. Only don't get the query_buidler working as i'm in Symfony version 2.7.10 this code is to new. How can I make a query from the database to get all countries and set the default?

Comment: The query_builder is not a new feature at all, it should work in 2.7.*. Did you put the use statement ? (use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;) ? And if you did, do you have a repository to your Country Entity ?

Comment: Yes I have added the use. The error is on the orderBy option, when this is removed it works except the default value is not set? OrderBy gives the error that the name_en does not exists but it is there.

Comment: is that name_en in your entity ? Or nameEn ? Because in symfony, you don't care about DB names, only in what you defined in your entity class.

Comment: Thanks, thats it. The only thing that is now not working is the default value. With 'data' => '37' it is also not working? The value 37 is the ManyToOne linked ID for the Netherlands.

Comment: when you create the form, just set the country : $country = $em->getRepository('YourPath:Country')->findOneByNameEn('nl) ; and then $client->setCountry($country);

Comment: Thanks, but my form is buildup with multiple entities so this is not working. I have made a new question as it is to complex to explain in a comment box. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248701/set-default-value-of-dropdown-menu-in-a-symfony-form-that-is-build-with-two-enit

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing something about how database stores the relationships.

**The first problem**: you don't need this:

```
@ORM\Column(name="country_code", type="string", length=2)
```

... Because `@ORM\ManyToOne` already describes the schema for this property.

And here we meet **the second problem**: `@ORM\ManyToOne` creates an integer column, which contains an ID of the appropriate Country entity. Which means, when you create a form field for this property, it doesn't know which property should it render as a string representation, because your address book (or whatever you called it) entity stores only digits, not the country code.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly what I want is not possible. An @ORM\ManyToOne link only supports the primary ID if the entity as the linking element? Indeed the first problem line was there so the __tosting() value can be stored.