# Set default value of dropdown menu in a Symfony form that is build with two enitites

Tags: symfony

I have a bit complex Symfony form that uses two entities. A account and a user entity that are linked with a OneToMany link. The field Country is a third entity that has the Country data in it.

**The link in the User entity:**

```
       /**
       * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Account", inversedBy="users")
       * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id")
       */
       protected $account;
```

**Code of the User formtype:**

```
  $builder
     ->add('account', new AccountType());
```

**Code of the Account formtype:**

```
    $builder
        ->add('country', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyBundle:Country',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->orderBy('c.nameEn', 'ASC');
            },
            'choice_label' => 'nameEn',
            'data' => '37',
        ));
```

**Code controller:**

```
    $user = new User();
    $user->getAccount()->setCountry("37");
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
```

In the middle code line in the controller I'm tried to set the default value of the field Country to its primairy ID 37. So the form starts with that Country as default. But this gives an PHP error code already on the syntax. Looks like the second entity is not loaded yet? Any idees?

Comment: You can't use setCountry("37"), because you have just created entity $user and getAccount() method returns NULL ! You should use "data" attribute to set default value (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#data).

Comment: Or maybe you need to create $account entity first and assign it to $user....

Comment: I have tried to create the account first but then the from cannot be saved because the ManyToOne is in the wrong way. Only option is the build the form buttom up. I also tried setting the data field, see my updates Account formtype but this is not working?